# Git: Temporary merges in a parallel fix work flow

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm in this situation where we have `master`, `fix-a` and `fix-b` branches.

```
| A fix-a wip (HEAD of fix-a)
|/
| 
| B fix-b wip good enough (HEAD of fix-b)
|/  
M  (HEAD of master)
|
```

Say I'm working on `fix-a` while someone else is working on `fix-b`. `fix-a` and `fix-b` are not dependent on each other and can each be merged into `master` when done, in any order. However, having *issue-b* fixed, would make working with *issue-a* more convenient. And now *issue-b* is fixed-enough-for-me, is not complete yet, so not merged into `master`. So basically I want to merge `fix-b` into `fix-a`, but when merge `fix-a` into `master` not include the changes from `fix-b` — considering `fix-b` will continue to diverge and I don't want the half baked fix in my branch.

So I merge `fix-b` into `fix-a` and continue hacking.

```
| E  a fixed! (HEAD of fix-a)
| |
| D  merge fix-b in to fix-a
| |\
| | A  fix-a wip
| |/
|/| C  fix-b still wip (HEAD of fix-b)
| |/
| B  fix-b wip good enough
|/  
M  (HEAD of master)
|
```

now I want to merge the changes `A` and `E` into master. So I checkout `E`, do a `git rebase -i` and drop `B`. Then merge into `master`.

The question is, is there a more elegant way to do this? imagine `A` and `B` being long chain of commits. `git rebase -i` is sort-of tedious work. I would like to say, at merge-commit `D` follow parent `A`.

Answer (score 0):

> now I want to merge the changes A and E into master

Just merge. I don't see what the rebase dance was for. E has parent D, and D has parent A, so the changes wrought by A are still in E, and after the merge, A will still be right there in the history of master as one of the merge commit's ancestors. There is no more to desire.

It may be that your hesitation is due to a misperception that A and E are changesets. They are not. A commit is snapshot of all the files at that time. The merge commit D includes files that enact whatever A did, and the commit E includes them too. (Unless in the course of preparing E you deleted those files or acted in such a way as to undo whatever A wrought, but of course you did not — your whole goal was to *use* what A contributed, not to contradict it.)

It may also be that your original desire was really not a merge at all, but to sort of "borrow" A into your branch. In that case you should have just cherry-picked it. You could then do a local interactive rebase of the next commit(s) to squash it into A. In this way it would *look* as if you came up with the features from A independently. I don't approve of that, because you are now lying about where these features came from, but it would be a lot cleaner, in my view, than trying to backtrack over a merge commit.

Comment: The rebase in to discard changes from B. As if D never happened. It was only there for my convenience. Not related to fixing _a_.

Comment: Well that’s why I suggest you should have cherry picked A to start with. You did full fledged merge with merge commit and now you are regretting it.

Comment: hmm.. how do I discard the changes brought in (borrowed) by cherry-picking? Wouldn't the changes be as-if I made the changes my self. At least with a merge (or rebase on) there are commits that I can later drop out.

Comment: I don't think you understand my situation. Before D there were A and B. I want A. I want B only temporaryly, then to throw away B.

Comment: But you needed the state of B in order to do your good stuff. You don't want to reverse B. That would do bad things to the code you took so much trouble to write.

Comment: Point is I _don't need_ B. Nothing I do depends on B.

Answer (score 0):

I do games like this every once in a while.... it's manageable, but it requires a little bit more effort when you want to move stuff around.... and *merges* are not a good idea (in terms of getting the changes from a feature while working with another).

Say you develop `fea-A` and `fea-B` separately. Then you want to get `fea-B` on top of `fea-A`, just because it's fun:

```
git checkout fea-B
git rebase fea-A # assuming fea-A was started _after_ fea-B was started
```

Then, `fea-A` got more work (without rebasing)... how can you get `fea-B` to have those changes:

```
git checkout fea-B
git rebase fea-A # no problem.
```

One tricky part (not the only one) is if `fea-A` moves away from its current base (on a rebase). Then `fea-B` is kind of *left hanging*. You might try

```
git checkout fea-B
git rebase fea-A
```

And this is a **no go**. You are rebasing the revisions of fea-B... *plus* the original `fea-A` revisions. And is that a problem? Well, yes... because `fea-A` might have been modified heavily when it was rebased.... even rebuilt from scratch with completely different content. You *do not* want to rebase the stuff you have for `fea-A`. So you should try this instead:

```
git checkout fea-B
git rebase --onto fea-A fea-B~3 fea-B # assuming fea-B is only 3 revisions
```

Last, but not least, how about you want to get them separate again:

```
git checkout fea-B
git rebase --onto main fea-A fea-B
```

Which will get `fea-B` on top of `main` again, without all the `fea-A` stuff.

And keep the branches straight without merges. It will be much simpler to handle to move stuff around.

Comment: I've never heard of the rebase --onto flag, I'll look into this. Thankyou. I kinda like the idea that history is preserved using merge over rebase. Not that I ever do, but I imagine someday wanting to checkout SOME_MERGE_COMMIT^2 to view the changes at that time.

Comment: great! don't get me wrong. I am not opposed to merges... when the PRs will be merged into the `main` branch.... but while features are being developed and so on? I think they should be straight lines. It's simpler to deal with them.